# prerequisites for calculus

Tags: calculus

What are the prerequisites for learning calculus?
I have experience in proof writing, trigonometric functions,permutations and combinations,naive set theory, mathematical induction,
and the abstract notion of functions. Should I start calculus or should I complete some other prerequisites?I want to learn calculus more by theorems and proofs than computation. Can I learn
calculus theorems without much experience in computational calculus? Is it mandatory to do computational calculus first?How many hours should i devote to it?Can I self study calculus?

Comment: You need solid algebra skills; almost nothing that you mention is a true prerequisite (trigonometric functions can be learned along-the-way, on a “just-in-time” basis). Knowing what a function is might be nice, but it’s usually just the first thing you need in calculus. Note that calculus is about *calculation* (hence the name). If what you want is the abstract mathematical theory, that’s called “Analysis”, not calculus.

Answer (score 0):

Calculus has many levels. The prerequisite is pre-calculus. [Here](https://cec-code-lab.aps.edu/downloads/precalculus-text.pdf) is a free online pre-calculus textbook. If you are above this level, then you are ready for Calculus I.